# Confirmation window "Cancel" button not working

Tags: laravel, button, alert, confirmation, cancel-button

I'm building my first laravel project and I'm trying to make a confirmation window for my "Delete" button. The thing is that confirmation window shows up, but whether I press "confirm" or "cancel" it would delete data anyway. Can you help me out?

Here is my code:

```html
<a id="demo" href="{{route('viewfile2.delete2', $down->id)}}?{{time()}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:red;"onclick="myFunction()">
      Delete
    </button>
</a>
                      
    
    
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
         return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your form submitting data, replace `type="submit"` by `type="button"` and replace your JavaScript code by testing the return value of the confirm call, if it's true then submit your form programmatically.

For testing purposes I made this:

```html
    <form id="deleteFormId" action="http://yourwebsite.kom/doDelete/4598765">
    <button type="button" onclick='myFunction()'>Delete</button>
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>

    <script>
    function myFunc(){
    if (window.confirm("Are You Sure ?")) { 
      document.querySelector('#deleteFormId').submit();
    }
    }
    </script>
```

See the [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/redhax/pen/OJyOMZj) and [Document.querySelector() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: When I do that I still get the confirmation window to show, but now both buttons, Confirm and delete, won't delete data... before both deleted data, now neither of them delete data.

Comment: I got it.
had to change:
 document.querySelector('#deleteFormId').submit();
to
document.getElementById('deleteFormId').submit();

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad that it helped ! for future users : I made this codePen https://codepen.io/redhax/pen/OJyOMZj and for reference of document.querySlector, please take a look at this on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

This is as much as simple

```
<a href="{{route('viewfile2.delete2', $down->id)}}?{{time()">
     <i class="far fa-trash-alt trash_color" onclick="return confirm('If you delete {{$down->id}} it will be permanently deleted\nAre you sure?')"></i>. 
</a>
```